# AWS S3 ListBucketResult pagination without authentication?

Tags: shell, amazon-s3, pagination, xmlstarlet

I'm looking to get a simple listing of **all** the objects in a public S3 bucket.

I'm aware how to get a [listing with curl for upto 1000 results](http://dabase.com/e/14003/), though I do not understand how to paginate the results, in order to get a full listing. I think *marker* is a clue.

I do not want to use a SDK / library or authenticate. I'm looking for a couple of lines of shell to do this.

Comment: I've now setup a service demonstrating this http://s3.dabase.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
#!/bin/sh

# setting max-keys higher than 1000 is not effective
s3url=http://mr2011.s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com?max-keys=1000
s3ns=http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/

i=0
s3get=$s3url

while :; do
    curl -s $s3get > "listing$i.xml"
    nextkey=$(xml sel -T -N "w=$s3ns" -t \
        --if '/w:ListBucketResult/w:IsTruncated="true"' \
        -v 'str:encode-uri(/w:ListBucketResult/w:Contents[last()]/w:Key, true())' \
        -b -n "listing$i.xml")
    # -b -n adds a newline to the result unconditionally, 
    # this avoids the "no XPaths matched" message; $() drops newlines.

    if [ -n "$nextkey" ] ; then
        s3get=$s3url"&marker=$nextkey"
        i=$((i+1))
    else
        break
    fi
done
```

Comment: I get an error: `error in arguments: no -t or --template options found`. Please use `http://mr2011.s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com` which has >1000 object to test upon.

Comment: Oh, I didn't clue in that the linked page was yours. It also turns out you can set max-keys to a lower number for testing (higher than 1000 doesn't work though).

Comment: I get `None of the XPaths matched; to match a node in the default namespace
use '_' as the prefix (see section 5.1 in the manual).
For instance, use /_:node instead of /node
`

Comment: Ok, I've writtem my own solution that looks like: http://ix.io/aGY Needs re-factoring for multiple buckets by doing a IsTruncated test properly.

Comment: Ah, I was using a version without that message. Added a little hack to avoid it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've built upon it here https://github.com/kaihendry/s3listing/blob/master/listing.sh